# Cannot set/read Django simple history change reason

Tags: django-simple-history

I'm using the simple_history package for Django and would like to record whether the user creates, updates or deletes a model object. I thought I'd use the history change reason for that purpose and in models.py do something like

```
def save(...):
    if not self.id:
        self.id = uuid()
        self.changeReason = 'create'
    else:
        self.changeReason = 'update'
    super(MyModel, self).save(...)
```

When I save the model this 'changeReason' field seems to be set (at least there are no errors) but when I try to read it in a test case like .history.first().instance.changeReason it complains that the field 'changeReason' does not exist. The history.first() call works so I do have a history record.

I have SIMPLE_HISTORY_HISTORY_CHANGE_REASON_USE_TEXT_FIELD = True in settings.py

I'm probably overlooking something basic but I can't seem to figure out what...

Thanks,

Comment: As of django-simple-history v2.10, the field for setting value to history before saving is called `_change_reason`. 

The instance for the historical record and database column name remains `history_change_reason`.

Answer (score 0):

My bad...

Setting `self.changeReason = 'create'` in the model is the right thing to do. The problem was incorrect checking of the change reason in my test case.

I tried

```
self.assertEqual(<object>.history.first().instance.changeReason, 'create')
```

but it should be

```
self.assertEqual(<object>.history.first().history_change_reason, 'create')
```

That passed the test :)

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct for checking the `changeReason`; however, whether or not a record was created, updated, or deleted is already tracked in the history table by default in the `history_type` field.